# I can post to my IIS server with c# but get a 405 error when posting to the same server with Javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, post, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to post to the same server as my client on Windows 10.  I can post from a c# program in the code behind but not to the same url using Javascript... which fails with a 405 Method Not Allowed error.  The Javascript code looks like:

```
var xHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xHttp.open("POST", url);
xHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xHttp.onload = function () {
    top.idxDisplayMessage(this.responseText);
};
xHttp.send(data);
```

Same error with jQuery:

```
function postHttpDoc(url, data) {
    // Data is in the proper object format here for jQuery
    var jqxhr = $j.post(url + '?' + data, function () {
        alert("success");
    })
        .done(function () {
            alert("second success");
        })
        .fail(function () {
            alert("error");
        })
        .always(function () {
            alert("finished");
        });
}
```

I've checked IIS's Handler Mappings, ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0 and verbs say: GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,DELETE,PUT

I've added the following to web.config:

```
<system.webServer>
 <security>
    <requestFiltering>
        <verbs allowUnlisted="false">
            <add verb="GET" allowed="true" />
            <add verb="POST" allowed="true" />
            <add verb="DELETE" allowed="true" />
            <add verb="PUT" allowed="true" />
        </verbs>
    </requestFiltering>
</security>
```

But nothing has fixed the issue yet.  What am I missing or not doing correctly?

Comment: You need a form and that form has to be serialized in your post call if you want to send form data to the back server: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/sending-html-form-data-part-1#sending-form-data-via-ajax

Comment: Just updated the post... In the jQuery example, "data" has been formatted into the proper object format.  No forms are involved here, just a series of named string values.   The issue is with the call to the server.  Both Javascript and jQuery give the 405 error.

Comment: If no form then why not use json?

Comment: Not sure how that fixes a 405 error...

Answer (score 0):

Well, it turns out "What" you're trying to post to counts and I wasn't diligent enough to look at that first.  I was posting to a gRPC client which is different than a normal web page. In the program.cs there is this code:

```
var app = builder.Build();
app.MapGet("/", (HttpContext context) => {
... code here ...
});
```

Obviously, MapGet is not a post.  So, all I needed to do is change to:

```
var app = builder.Build();
app.MapPost("/", (HttpContext context) => {
... code here ...
});
```

And the thing worked.  My bad for not realizing sooner that what you're posting to also has an effect on the Get/Post.